# How to create real time tracking apps like Uber using react native?

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am working with real time tracking application using react-native. 
And want the accuracy Uber and Swiggy and other tracking application do. 
I am using [react-native-geolocation-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service), but not getting accuracy like Uber.

I just want to know how Uber track realtime? Does they request to server every single second? 
Because there position is moving continuously, which is not possible in my app. I am saving coordinates after every 15 seconds.

1. Please suggest what can I use for making accurate path?
2. And what does Uber and other tacking apps used for tracking? And how they get realtime data for every single second?

Answer (score 0):

For getting real time location you can use paid services like https://www.navixy.com/. I have used this service year ago and they are providin lot of functionalities track Android device with their API's.

Comment: it's not native program's they are providing to you API's for working with their system. You are implementing it to your, web, desktop, mobile and etc app's.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Firebase Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) or [cloud firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). It works like realtime data update.

Store lat long on firestore/database whenever there is change in position and within a second you will be able to get those data on other end.

It is having nice performance when it comes to real time data update. I have used it with one of the native application before a year.

For react native, you can use [Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) api which is having [watchposition](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#watchposition) method. It will be invoked whenever there is location change.

Comment: I have already used Geolocation api but sometimes it's getting coordinates very far from current location, which makes map weird and having issue in calculating distance also because of wrong coordinates.